# Grant access to private constructor without friends?

Tags: c++, constructor, private, friend

I am working on some code, where I encountered a situation similar to this one:

```
struct Bar;

struct Foo{
    friend struct Bar;
private:
    Foo(){}
    void f(){}
    void g(){}
};

struct Bar {
   Foo* f;
   Bar()  { f = new Foo();}
   ~Bar() { delete f;}
};

int main(){
  Bar b;
}
```

I would prefer to have `Bar` not as `friend` of `Foo`, because besides `Foo`s constructor `Bar` does not need access to any of `Foo`s private methods (and thus should not have access). Is there a way to allow only `Bar` to create `Foo`s without making them friends?

**PS**: realized that the question might not be 100% clear. I don't mind if it is via friends or not, just the fact that all `Bar` has access to all private methods is disturbing me (which is usually the case with `friends`) and that is what I want to avoid. Fortunately none of the answers given so far had a problem with that lousy formulation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is precisely what the [attorney-client](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Friendship_and_the_Attorney-Client) idiom is for:

```
struct Bar;

struct Foo {
    friend struct FooAttorney;
private:
    Foo(){}
    void f(){}
    void g(){}
};

class FooAttorney {
  static Foo* makeFoo() { return new Foo; }
  friend struct Bar;
};

struct Bar {
   Foo* f;
   Bar()  { f = FooAttorney::makeFoo();}
   ~Bar() { delete f;}
};

int main(){
  Bar b;
}
```

In a code imitates life fashion, the class declares an attorney that will mediate the secrets it's willing to share with the selected parties.

Comment: Thanks for turning the "No. But..." comment into a nice answer. I was already afraid there was a reason I could not use it for the constructor

Comment: @tobi303 Sorry about the scare. Two seconds after commenting I realized I was trying to answer your question in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to introduce another class, you can shrink the circle of friendship and make `Bar`'s constructor `Foo`'s friend. It requires `Bar`'s definition to be available to `Foo`, and it still gives `Bar`'s constructor unrestricted access to `Foo`'s private implementation:

```
struct Foo;

struct Bar {
   Foo* f;
   Bar();
   ~Bar();
};

struct Foo{
    friend Bar::Bar();
private:
    Foo(){}
    void f(){}
    void g(){}
};

Bar::Bar() : f(new Foo()) {
}

Bar::~Bar() {
    delete f;
}
```

This does not achieve exactly what you want, but it makes friendship a lot more targeted.

Comment: why not exactly what I want? Unfortunately currently `Bar` needs to know `Foo`s definition, but that might change once if fix the friendship issue.

Comment: @tobi303 This isn't exactly what you want, because you asked for restricting what a friend can do, while this approach restricts who is the friend instead. The constructor of `Bar` still retains full range of access due to its friendship with `Foo`. Of course, depending on a situation this may not be a bad thing.

Comment: ah yes, got it. Actually I wouldnt mind if it was possible without friends. I dont like the concept of friends at all (i mean the C++ one ;). With this approach at least the scope where I have to be careful not to do something stupid is limited to its minimum

Answer (score 3):

One way that occurred to me was to have an internal `class` that makes `Bar` its friend so only `Bar` can create it and that internal `class` can be used as an additional parameter to `Foo` constructor so only the `class`'s friends can invoke it.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // only friends of the special key can invoke the constructor
    // or any member function that includes it as a dummy parameter
    class special_key {friend class Bar; special_key(){}};

    // making special_key a dummy parameter makes sure only friends of
    // the special key can invoke the function
    Foo(special_key) {}
    void f(){}
    void g(){}
};

class Bar
{
public:
    // only Bar functions can create the special key
    Bar() { f = std::make_unique<Foo>(Foo::special_key()); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> f;
};
```

As well as restricting access to specific functions this technique also allows the use of smart pointer `make` functions which direct friendship does not.

Comment: I was thinking into that direction first, though my solution would have been  a lot messier

Comment: @tobi303 I just realized that this technique also allows you to use smart pointers which direct friendship does not.